# Zipf's Song - Finding the error or correction in approach

Tags: python

I have been trying to solve this puzzle that has been posted by Spotify, but after seeing and trying several approaches, I am not able to get a positive answer from their system, although my testings are ok.

I propose two of my solutions. They are pretty similar except for the quality calculation approach and the std input read. The code can get refinement, I am interested in correct result.

So I would kindly ask if you could point me my error and misunderstanding. Thank you

First one:

```
import sys, re

try:
    p = re.compile('^[a-z0-9_]{1,30}$')
    theOutput = sys.stdout.write
    line = sys.stdin.readline().strip().split()
    n = int(line[0])
    if n < 1 or n > 50000:
        raise Exception("First inputted number is out of range (1<=n<=50000)")
    else:
        m = int(line[1])
        if m < 1 or m > n:
            raise Exception("Second inputted number is out of range (1<=m<=n)")
        else:
            song_freq = []
            freq_max = 10**12
            for i in range(n):
                line = sys.stdin.readline().strip().split()
                line[0] = int(line[0])
                if line[0] > freq_max:
                    raise Exception("Frequency of song " + str(i+1) + "(" + str(line[0]) + ") out of range")
                if p.match(line[1]):
                    song_freq.append((int(line[0]), line[1]))
                else:
                    raise Exception("Songname " + line[1] + " at line " + str(i+1) + " is not valid")
            song_zipf = [((song_freq[0][0]/float(i+1)), song_freq[i][1]) for i in range(n)]
            song_qual = [((song_freq[i][0]/song_zipf[i][0]), song_freq[i][1]) for i in range(n)]
            song_qual = sorted(song_qual, key = lambda tup:tup[0], reverse = True)
            for j in range(m):
                theOutput(song_qual[j][1]+'\n')                      
except Exception as e:
    print "Exception:", e.message
```

Second one:

```
import sys, re

try:
    p = re.compile('^[a-z0-9_]{1,30}$')
    theInput = sys.stdin.readline().split('\n')
    theOutput = sys.stdout.write
    line = theInput.pop(0).strip().split()
    n = int(line[0])
    if n < 1 or n > 50000:
        raise Exception("First inputted number is out of range (1<=n<=50000)")
    else:
        m = int(line[1])
        if m < 1 or m > n:
            raise Exception("Second inputted number is out of range (1<=m<=n)")
        else:
            songlist = []
            freq_max = 10**12
            for i in range(n):
                line = theInput.pop(0).strip().split()
                line[0] = int(line[0])
                if line[0] > freq_max:
                    raise Exception("Frequency of song " + str(i+1) + "(" + str(line[0]) + ") out of range")
                if p.match(line[1]):
                    songlist.append((int(line[0]), line[1]))
                else:
                    raise Exception("Songname " + line[1] + " at line " + str(i+1) + " is not valid")
            song_qual = [((songlist[i][0]*(i+1)), songlist[i][1]) for i in range(n)]
            song_qual = sorted(song_qual, key = lambda tup:tup[0], reverse = True)
            for j in range(m):
                theOutput(song_qual[j][1]+'\n')                      
except Exception as e:
    print "Exception:", e.message
```

Comment: Please provide a link to the problem.

Comment: https://www.spotify.com/it/jobs/tech/zipfsong/

Excuse me for missing to include that :)